# Formal explication of $dx/dt = v(x)$ implies that $dt/dx=1/v(x)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

The tittle is all about my question.

What is the formal explication of the fact that $dx/dt = v(x)$ implies that $dt/dx=1/v(x)$?

Is that via geometry? analysis? differentiable forms?

Can you give me reasons for that? Thanks.

(Here, $v(x)$ is a function that only depends on $x$, with $x$ a real number)

Comment: Search inverse function theorem on website or your calculus textbook. It's the same thing with different notation.

Answer (score 3):

$$x=f(t),\qquad t=f^{-1}(x)$$
$$f(f^{-1}(x))=x=Id(x)$$
**If** $(f^{-1})'$ exists (the hard part of IFT), then by the chain rule:
$$f'(f^{-1}(x))(f^{-1})'(x)=Id'(x)=1$$
and
$$(f^{-1})'(x)=\frac1{f'(f^{-1}(x))}.$$